# Raw use of parameterized class 'RedisTemplate' warning

Tags: java, spring, redis

This is how I declare and inject:

```
    private final RedisTemplate redisTemplate;
    @Autowired
    public SomeController(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }
```

This is how I use it:

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, dtoList, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Where key is of type String, and dtoList is of type List; 
but the ide complains that `Unchecked call to 'set(K, V, long, TimeUnit)' as a member of raw type 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.ValueOperations'`  when I set the value.

if instead, `private final RedisTemplate<String, List<?>> redisTemplate;` were used, the warning is gone,; But I don't want to specifically enforce the type because I might be setting values of different types later.